# Imagemagick is increasing filesize on ezpublish 4.7 enterprise

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, ezpublish

I am using imagemagic on eZpublish with image.ini.append.php. The quality is set to 100. But the image file size(jpg) is increasing(almost double) after the conversion, even if the resolution is same as the original image in the converted one.

**Is there any way to keep the filesize same or smaller by keeping the quality intact?**

**My Settings in the image.ini.append.php:**

```html
[ImageMagick]
IsEnabled=true
Filters[]=cropfromcenter=-gravity center -crop %1x%2+0+0 +repage
Filters[]=cropfromtop=-gravity north -crop %1x%2+0+0 +repage
Filters[]=thumbnail=-resize x%4 -resize %3x< -resize 50% -gravity center -crop %1x%2+0+0 +repage

[MIMETypeSettings]
Quality[]
Quality[]=image/jpeg;100
                                                    
                                                    
[reference]
HideFromRelations=enabled
Filters[]
Filters[]=geometry/scalewidthdownonly=1600
                                                    

[custom_1200]
GUIName=1200px
Reference=reference
Filters[]
Filters[]=geometry/scalewidthdownonly=1200
```

Comment: for the same filesize. why do you apply a filter on that file in your template at all ? just use the raw name of your image and you'll have it without any filter and effect without imagemagick.